Strapi Context Typescript
I'm developing an application using Strapi and TypeScript. Is was wondering what is the correct type for the ctx parameter that is e.g. passed to a Middleware or a Controller?
It was mentioned here that we can use import { Context } from "koa"; to provide a type for ctx.
But when doing so I'm running in quite some TypeScript errors, e.g. here:
// path: ./src/api/[api-name]/middlewares/my-middleware.ts

export default async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<any>) => {
  const newName = ctx.request.body.name;
  if (!newName) {
    return ctx.badRequest('name is missing', { foo: 'bar' })
  }
  await next();
}

I would get an error that ctx.badRequest seems to only expect a single parameter, even though this example is taken from the official Strapi documentation.

Did you figure it out? Have the same question

Although is a weird one, digging in the types files, found that the Context is an import from koa, and I was able to use it like this:
import { Context, Next } from 'koa';

export default {
  exampleAction: async (ctx: Context, next: Next): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      ctx.body = 'ok';
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.body = err;
    }
  }
};

